# Namespace not found in deployed site; works locally

Tags: .net, asp.net, deployment, namespaces

My hosted website is not working, and is giving an error.

```
**The name 'General' does not exist in the current context**

Line 19:     if (passedArgument == "true")
Line 20:     {
Line 21:         General.Session.UserID = "";
Line 22:         General.Session.UserName = "";
Line 23:         General.Session.ShoppingCart = null
```

General is, as you can see, a namespace containing the class Session.

```
               namespace General
  {
/// <summary>
/// Summary description for Session
/// </summary>
public class Session
{
    public Session()
    {
    }
```

My service provider tells me I should check my code, but it's working just fine on my local machine.  Why is it not finding the namespace, and generating the error?

Comment: It might be helpful if you could tell us which language you're using ... maybe a little about where "General" came from, that kind of thing, otherwise your description is about as useful as "A namespace reference isn't working on my server, but it works on my local machine" :P

Comment: i am using asp.net , rest portion i don't understand , maybe this will help its in app code folder now i see all the classes in appcode folder are generating error when used in the code

Comment: So is "General" in its own class file?  Do you compile before you upload to the server, or just leave all of the uncompiled code in app_code?  Is there other similar code that's being executed successfully, or is it possible that none of your namespace references work?

Comment: @Confused - The fact you don't understand something about your own code is an indication you need to do some more research.

Comment: i did compiled , and none of the namespace reference is working

Comment: It sounds like it'll be a simple problem, but it's really difficult to tell from your description.  If I were you, I'd ask someone - preferably someone you know in the real world - to take a look.  We're pretty good at answering questions with all the relevant information, but it's hard to know what's relevant in this case.

Comment: hmm ..sorry for that , but please any reason you can tell why the namespace reference is not working on server and working fine on my local machine

Comment: The server's presumably not compiling it, or loading the compiled library if it's precompiled as you said.  It could be that it's in the wrong location in the filesystem, and not being picked up because of that ... but I can't be sure of that.

Comment: So , i just compiled it again n updated the files still not working so it means no issue at my end rite there is nothing to blame me for this?

Comment: It could be the way you've uploaded it, it could be that you've compiled it for the wrong version, it could be that the server doesn't support the binaries you're uploading ... I can't absolve you of blame, but I can't say you're definitely at fault either.  Sorry :)

Comment: so any comment what should i say to the service provide what to check for?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Usually, this means that you are running in a sub-directory (i.e. not the site-root), and that directory is not marked as an *application* in IIS.

Basically, App_Code is resolved *relative to the nearest application* (or the root otherwise). So if your app is at `/someapp`, then instead of looking in `/someapp/App_Code`, it is looking in `/App_Code`. Where your files aren't.

If this is the case, mark the folder as an application in IIS. This varies between IIS versions, but the end-result is that the folder icon should display a cog in IIS.

Comment: maybe you are right , the path given to me i created a folder there and then copied the files into it maybe that is causing the problem so i should just upload the files

Comment: @ConfusedCoder that depends: who has access to IIS?

Comment: you were right i copied all the files without creating folder and its working fine now thank you

Answer (score 0):

I've had issues with code not compiling when using "Client Profile" as oppose to the full .NET runtime (in this case, 4.0).

One thing to check is if your provider is running the full runtime. You could also try changing the target framework for your project and see if it throws the same error.

For web hosting, it doesn't make any sense to just run Client Profile, but maybe they've installed it incorrectly?

Comment: an asp.net app *can't* be using the client profile; none of asp.net exists there.

Comment: i not sure what your are saying but i do see a aspnet_client folder in my website that i have not created

Comment: @ConfusedCoder that is the ASP.NET client-side validation scripts, etc. Don't worry about that. Completely unrelated to client-profile.